# Is it possible to generalise the values of $a$ and $b$ for these following expressions?

Tags: exponentiation, multivariate-polynomial

$a{}^b$ = m

$b{}^a$ = n

Find $a$ and $b$ in terms of $m$ and $n$

Such that $a,b,m,n$ $\in {}^+R$

I tried logging both sides and substituting the values. It forms an equation $n{}^\frac{1}{a} \ln (a) - \ln (m) = 0$

Comment: Also if not, why so… what are the limitations when it comes to equations like these with two variables

Comment: What have you found in your own attempts?

Comment: I tried logging both sides and substituting the values. It forms an equation : $n{}^\frac{1}{a} \ln (a) - \ln (m) = 0$

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form answer so you could try numerical methods instead.  And there may be multiple solutions: for example with $n=m=20$ you can have $(a,b) \approx (7.2801718,1.5090676)$ or $(1.5090676,7.2801718)$ or  $(2.8553085,2.8553085)$